# Add legend to alt.chart

Tags: python, charts, streamlit, altair

I am unable to add legend to my layered chart. Please advise how to add legend to this one.

```
a1 = alt.Chart(queried_data2).mark_line(strokeWidth=2,color="#FFAA00").encode(
    x=alt.X('MONTH:O', timeUnit="yearmonth" , axis=alt.Axis(format="%b %y") ), y='P_25').add_selection(
    selector1)

b1 = alt.Chart(queried_data2).mark_line(color='#ff2b2b').encode(
    x=alt.X('MONTH:O', timeUnit="yearmonth" , axis=alt.Axis(format="%b %y") ), y='P_75').add_selection(
    selector2)

c1 = alt.Chart(queried_data2).mark_line(color='#09ab3b').encode(
    x=alt.X('MONTH:O', timeUnit="yearmonth" , axis=alt.Axis(format="%b %y") ), y='P_90').add_selection(
    selector3)

d1 = alt.Chart(queried_data2).mark_line(color='#0068c9').encode(
    x=alt.X('MONTH:O', timeUnit="yearmonth" , axis=alt.Axis(format="%b %y") ), y='MEDIAN').add_selection(
    selector4)
z1 = alt.layer(a1, b1, c1, d1)
st.altair_chart(z1, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide full code includes import and data?